# How to resize of a image base on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I resize of a image base on screen size. Example:
I have a  tag (width:1349, height: 449) and a image in div (width:78, height:78). When display image in div I fix for width of image is 60 and height is 60. I saw in mobile screen then the size of image still keep state so now I want to image display automatic resize base on screen example: in iPhone 4 the image have size (20x20) or percent of it in the screen. How can I use the formular for calculate it? This is my code jquery for calculate it.

```
            var mw = $("#c").width();
            var mh = $("#c").height();
            console.log();

            var img = new Image();
            img.src = './img/photo-circle.png';
            var wdImg = img.width;
            var hiImg = img.height;
            var ratioImg = wdImg/hiImg;
            var ratioDiv = mw/mh;

            if (ratioDiv > 1) {
                var newwd = wdImg*(mh/hiImg);
                alert(newwd);
            } ;
```

Comment: Media queries and/or user agent recognition.

Comment: You can set the image width and height as a percentage of its parent div.

Comment: I am using canvas to draw it so I calculate by javascript. How can I use the formular for calculate it with percentages ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using percentages to achieve dynamic resizing of your elements.  Then, as long as the parents are also dynamically resizing, their children will as well.  For example, `width: 30%;` instead of `width: 100px;`

Comment: I using canvas to draw it so I calculate by javascript. How can I use the formular for calculate it with percentages ?

Answer (score 0):

use the css unit vh and vw

each unit is worth 1% of the screen size

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

example:

```
.item {
    height: 20vw;
    width: 20vw;
}
```

If the screen width is 100pixels, .item would be 20px by 20px

Comment: I using javascript to calculate it. Please, check my code above and help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use a bootstrap class called "img-responsive" at your img tag .
That's all , It will be responsive on any screen.

Comment: OP hasn't indicated that he/she is using Bootstrap as a library.